# Bundle Optimization causing Invalid Invocation error in jquery-ui

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, optimization, bundle

I am having the strangest error and it's driving me up the wall. At the moment I have the following two bundles...

```
 var jquery = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
                , "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"
                , "~/Scripts/materialize/materialize.js"
                , "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.debug.js"
                , "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js"
                , "~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-{version}.js");

var jsfiles = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Assets/js")
                  .IncludeDirectory("~/Assets/js", "*.js", true);

   bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js", OptimizationMode.WhenDisabled);
```

Within the ASSETS folder there is the following file

```
jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"
```

When I debug and run locally everything is fine. However when I **turn on** following

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

The jquery-ui file mentioned is throwing the following error...

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Which relates to this block of code

```
return u?n.isFunction(u[e])&&"_"!==e.charAt(0)?(i=u[e].apply(u,o),i!==u&&i!==t?(s=i&&i.jquery?s.pushStack(i.get()):i,!1):t):n.error("no such method '"+e+"' for "+r+" widget instance")
:n.error("cannot call methods on "+r+" prior to initialization; attempted to call method '"+e+"'")})
:this.each(function(){var t=n.data(this,f);});
```

I don't even know where to start debugging it? Could the minification engine be doing something?

Comment: try replacing name `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js` with `jquery-ui-1.10.3.js`

Comment: I did try this after I found a related SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, javascript resourced with `.min` in the filename are automatically excluded from bundling, so referencing the unminified version of the JQuery UI document should fix it (or alternatively, but not recommended - remove the `.min` from your existing filename.

Comment: I am aware if the default ignores. I have tried removing the .min and .custom names. I would like to point out though that the code block that throws the error is in the Jquery UI file in question so it must be loading?